# save string variable in NSMutableArray -Error

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I'm new to iOS and its development. Here I'm passing string value to `saveStringpath` variable then I want to save it in type NSMutable array `saveStrings` but I'm getting:

```
thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=2  type breakspoint
```

please help me.

```
//here i need to save these data in NSMutable array
-(void)saveNSMutablearray:(NSString*)saveStringpath
{

    //start Mutable array to save this values
    NSMutableArray *saveStrings =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [saveStrings addObject:saveStrings];

    NSString *test = [saveStrings objectAtIndex:0];


    NSLog(@"JSON:-----vm %@", test);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of wrong variable name. In your code you are adding array into array, so to solve the problem please change this line:

```
[saveStrings addObject:saveStrings];
```

into that one:

```
[saveStrings addObject:saveStringpath];
```

and the problem is gone :)

Comment: thanks and sorry for being stupid

Comment: human thing is to make mistakes, happy to be able to help :) good luck!